# do you mind me vs do you mind if

Tags: word-choice, gerunds

Ok , I have two sentences :

Do you mind if I open the window?
Do you mind me opening the window?

Are both of them correct?
If yes , do they have the same meaning ?
Thanks for helping

Comment: Yes, they are both correct, and interchangeable in real-life contexts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both of your examples are correct, have the same meaning, and would be understood

> Do you mind if **I** open the window?
>   Do you mind **me** opening the window?

possibly more formal might be

> ***Would*** you mind if I open the window?

since you are asking about a condition in the *future*.

Comment: Forgive me if it sounds dumb , but I can't find the check box..
Where is it?

Comment: Oh nevermind , I think I've found it.